# Transition coverpoint using arrays

Tags: verilog, code-coverage, system-verilog

I have a situation where I have an array (`dlen`) as input to `covergroup`. I want to write a transition `coverpoint` as:

```
dlen_cp : coverpoint signal {
 Bins bin [] = dlen => dlen;
}
```

This is giving syntax error saying array can't be as it. Any solution for this issue? I am using VCS

I was able to use the array directly in a normal `coverpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors in the code you posted.

Verilog is case-sensitive; the keyword is `bins`, not `Bins`.

The transitions should be specified in parentheses: `()`.

You can not use a variable name like `dlen` to specify the transition.  You can use numeric values like: `(5 => 6)`.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 19.5.2 *Specifying bins for transitions*.

See also [How to write cover points for transitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663079/how-to-write-cover-points-for-transition-in-systemverilog)